# Color Change Render

Tags: color

Hello i am making a Blender Typography Lyric Animation and my text keeps coming out as black. I have successfully changed my background color but the text is still black.

Here is what colors I hope for after rendering
[image]
But Here Is What I Get After Rendering
[image]
Please Help Me

I Am Using Blender 2.79

[image]

Comment: Please show your material settings and specify what render engine you are using.

Comment: Posting your .blend file using http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ may help.

Comment: i added the stuff u requested

Comment: "but now the colors are to bright they look like this". Your light is too bright and/or your materials are too glossy. Moving the light to the side may help also.

Comment: I have rolled back your last edit. If you want ask a new question, ask a new one using this sites functionality, do not edit your original question the be the new one, as part of the purpose of this site is to preserve useful questions in case someone else has the same problem.

Comment: Also, please accept the answer that solved the problem for you.

Answer (score 2):

You either need to ad a light source to your scene, or you need to make your text object materials 'shadeless' in the shading panel of the properties editor.

Comment: omg thank you i added a sun light and put the strength to 250 and the colors showed up

Answer (score 0):

Are there any lights in the scene?

Also, viewport colors are NOT materials see if you have assigned materials to each text object. If you haven't that could also be one of the reasons why your render is appearing black.

Finally, if you have converted the texts to Objects (by pressing Alt+C > Mesh from curve, meta, surf, text), then select the objects then go into edit mode, select all surfaces by tapping 'A' and recalculate the normals using Ctrl+N.

**Edit :** Just check your scene, there are no light sources, after adding one, it renders fine.

Comment: omg thank you i added a sun light and put the strength to 250 and the colors showed up